# Nuxt/Auth-Next Redirect after Login and Logout Not Working

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

I've been using @nuxtjs/auth-next package for a certain pages of my project. Here are my nuxt auth configurations...

```
    strategies: {
        policies: {
            scheme: 'local',
            token: {
                global: false,
                type: '',
                required: true
            },
            redirect: {
                login: '/my-policies',
                logout: '/my-policies/login',
                user: '/my-policies/login',
                home: '/my-policies'
            },
            endpoints: {
                login: { url: '/policies/login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'token'},
                logout: { url: '/policies/logout', method: 'delete'},
                user: { url: '/policies/user', method: 'get'}
            },
            user: {
                property: ''
            },
        },
    }
```

The problem is, redirects never work. The `login` endpoint responses successfully and the nuxt auth triggers the `user` request. When that one is also successful, it redirects me to my homepage which is "/".
But in the redirect object in the nuxt.config file, I defined it to redirect to "/my-policies/" page.

Also when I logout by using `this.$auth.logout();` it redirects me to homepage as well.

I tried to redirect the page manually but still no luck...

Also tried to work with `rewriteRedirects`. When I set it to false, it redirects me to "/login" page when I logout.

So, the redirect object in my config never work. Is there anything I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would like to use callbackUrl parameter in the authentification method.

```
 await signIn(credentials,{ callbackUrl: '/' });
```

Lets have a look into the [documentation](https://sidebase.io/nuxt-auth/v0.6/application-side/session-access-and-management)